# Interface Builder is unable to open documents of type iPad XIB

Tags: ipad, interface-builder

What this error indicate?

Comment: Are you using the 3.2 (or above) SDK?

Answer (score 0):

I get a similar error.
"Interface Builder is unable to open documents of type CocoaTouch XIB."

I have the lastest SDK.